# Authentication and Role based authorization with Asp.net Webapi

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing Authentication/Authorization in our Webapi.Currently its working in basic http authentication which is
ofcourse just authentication.

We have to implement Role based authorization. What the best practice to go this way.

I am thinking to generate a token based on authentication and was wondering
if there is any to contain information in token that can tell me about user, its role , expiration date etc.
This token will be passed back and forth with every request.

How do i check for expiration of this token and extract information.
I am thinking not to store it in db to query database again for every requestto see if it expired or not. 
Whats the right way to do this.

I am open to suggestions and want to see whats being done related to this.

I am thinking to design our controller in a way that the REST url are transparent to the consumers of our services.
In Controller/HttpHandler we are able to figure out which role this id belongs to and bring the data accordingly.

Please suggest

Comment: Check this answer to the same question about using an  AuthorizationFilterAttribute here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881506/cross-platform-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api